# Создание Pretty Table с переменными

Tags: python, python-3.x, table

Задача вывести ссылки и количество упоминаний с помощью `Pretty Table`

Эти ссылки результат выполнения программы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно что бы все это выводилось с помощью `Pretty Table` с заголовками `word` и `match numbers`

```
import re, requests
from collections import Counter
from prettytable import PrettyTable

url_input = input("Enter url: ")

url_checked = re.findall(r'https?://\S+', url_input)[0] # берем первый элемент

if url_input != url_checked: # проверка валидности ссылки
    print("Entered url is invalid")
else:
    pass

response = requests.get(str(url_checked)) # запрос на введенную ссылку

result = re.findall(r'/[A-Za-z.]+/', response.text) # фильтрация ссылок

result.sort() # sorting by alphabet 

def count_words(List):
    for word, counter in Counter(List).most_common(): # sorting and printing list by counter value
        print(f"{word} matches {counter} times")

count_words(result)

pt = PrettyTable()
pt.header_names = ["word", "counter"]

def print_table(items):

print_table(result)
```

Comment: да, извините, сейчас дополню

Comment: уже дополнил, еще что то нужно?

Comment: я не могу решить этот вопрос потому что как раз не до конца понимаю как вообще сделать то что вы описали. Код который есть в вопросе - все что я смог написать

Comment: я ввожу ссылку в консоль, и с помощью requests.get и regex я получаю то что вы видите на картинке. Это мне и нужно перевести в таблицу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pt = PrettyTable(field_names=["word", "counter"])
pt.add_rows(list(Counter(result).most_common()))
print(pt)
```

вывод:

```
+------------------------------+---------+
|             word             | counter |
+------------------------------+---------+
|      /cdn.sstatic.net/       |    43   |
|     /stackoverflow.com/      |    33   |
|            /home/            |    29   |
|            /jobs/            |    5    |
|     /stackexchange.com/      |    5    |
|       /stackoverflow/        |    5    |
|          /product/           |    4    |
|        /endorsements/        |    2    |
|          /products/          |    2    |
|           /tagged/           |    2    |
|           /teams/            |    2    |
|           /users/            |    2    |
|          /Channels/          |    1    |
|          /Product/           |    1    |
|    /ajax.googleapis.com/     |    1    |
|   /chat.stackoverflow.com/   |    1    |
|         /directory/          |    1    |
|         /enterprise/         |    1    |
| /insights.stackoverflow.com/ |    1    |
|            /libs/            |    1    |
|        /linkedin.com/        |    1    |
|    /pixel.quantserve.com/    |    1    |
|  /sb.scorecardresearch.com/  |    1    |
|   /secure.quantserve.com/    |    1    |
|           /story/            |    1    |
|        /twitter.com/         |    1    |
|      /www.facebook.com/      |    1    |
|     /www.instagram.com/      |    1    |
+------------------------------+---------+
```